# Shiro Login Failed-- Illegael Arguement Exception - principal argument cannot be null

Tags: apache, authentication, shiro, jdbcrealm

This Delegating class Login code of Apatche Shiro . Its showing error on

```
   Subject subject = this.securityManager.login(this, token);
```

Error is Principal arguement cannot be null ..

> result = {AuthenticationException@7922} Method threw
>   'org.apache.shiro.authc.AuthenticationException' exception. 
>   detailMessage = "Authentication failed for token submission
>   [org.apache.shiro.authc.UsernamePasswordToken - 9876534357,
>   rememberMe=true].  Possible unexpected error? (Typical or expected
>   login exceptions should extend from AuthenticationException)."  cause
>   = {IllegalArgumentException@8066} "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: principal argument cannot be null."  stackTrace =
>   {StackTraceElement[70]@8067}   suppressedExceptions =
>   {Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList@7696}  size = 0

```
  public void login(AuthenticationToken token) throws AuthenticationException {
    this.clearRunAsIdentitiesInternal();
    Subject subject = this.securityManager.login(this, token);
    String host = null;
    PrincipalCollection principals;
    if (subject instanceof DelegatingSubject) {
        DelegatingSubject delegating = (DelegatingSubject)subject;
        principals = delegating.principals;
        host = delegating.host;
    } else {
        principals = subject.getPrincipals();
    }

    if (principals != null && !principals.isEmpty()) {
        this.principals = principals;
        this.authenticated = true;
        if (token instanceof HostAuthenticationToken) {
            host = ((HostAuthenticationToken)token).getHost();
        }

        if (host != null) {
            this.host = host;
        }

        Session session = subject.getSession(false);
        if (session != null) {
            this.session = this.decorate(session);
        } else {
            this.session = null;
        }

    } else {
        String msg = "Principals returned from securityManager.login( token ) returned a null or empty value.  This value must be non null and populated with one or more elements.";
        throw new IllegalStateException(msg);
    }
}






stackTrace = {StackTraceElement[70]@7843}
```

> 0 = {StackTraceElement@7701}
>   "org.apache.shiro.authc.AbstractAuthenticator.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticator.java:214)"
>   1 = {StackTraceElement@7702}
>   "org.apache.shiro.mgt.AuthenticatingSecurityManager.authenticate(AuthenticatingSecurityManager.java:106)"
>   2 = {StackTraceElement@7703}
>   "org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager.login(DefaultSecurityManager.java:274)"
>   3 = {StackTraceElement@7704}
>   "org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.login(DelegatingSubject.java:260)"
>   4 = {StackTraceElement@7705}
>   "com.hk.impl.service.auth.LoginServiceImpl.login(LoginServiceImpl.java:262)"
>   5 = {StackTraceElement@7706}
>   "com.hk.impl.service.auth.LoginServiceImpl.loginAuthenticatedUser(LoginServiceImpl.java:223)"
>   6 = {StackTraceElement@7707}
>   "com.hk.impl.service.auth.LoginServiceImpl.login(LoginServiceImpl.java:450)"
>   7 = {StackTraceElement@7708}
>   "com.hk.web.resource.UserResource.loginViaOTP(UserResource.java:365)" 
>   8 = {StackTraceElement@7709}
>   "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)"  9 =
>   {StackTraceElement@7710}
>   "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)"
>   10 = {StackTraceElement@7711}
>   "sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)"
>   11 = {StackTraceElement@7712}
>   "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)"  12 =
>   {StackTraceElement@7713}
>   "org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:139)"
>   13 = {StackTraceElement@7714}
>   "org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:295)"
>   14 = {StackTraceElement@7715}
>   "org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:249)"
>   15 = {StackTraceElement@7716}
>   "org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:236)"
>   16 = {StackTraceElement@7717}
>   "org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:376)"
>   17 = {StackTraceElement@7718}
>   "org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:199)"
>   18 = {StackTraceElement@7719}
>   "org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221)"
>   19 = {StackTraceElement@7720}
>   "org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)"
>   20 = {StackTraceElement@7721}
>   "org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)"
>   21 = {StackTraceElement@7722}
>   "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)"  22 =
>   {StackTraceElement@7723}
>   "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)"
>   23 = {StackTraceElement@7724}
>   "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)"
>   24 = {StackTraceElement@7725}
>   "org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)"
>   25 = {StackTraceElement@7726}
>   "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)"
>   26 = {StackTraceElement@7727}
>   "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)"
>   27 = {StackTraceElement@7728}
>   "com.hk.web.filter.PersonaCookieFilter.doFilter(PersonaCookieFilter.java:60)"
>   28 = {StackTraceElement@7729}
>   "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)"
>   29 = {StackTraceElement@7730}
>   "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)"
>   30 = {StackTraceElement@7731}
>   "com.hk.web.filter.GoogleBotFilter.doFilter(GoogleBotFilter.java:102)"
>   31 = {StackTraceElement@7732}
>   "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)"
>   32 = {StackTraceElement@7733}
>   "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)"
>   33 = {StackTraceElement@7734}
>   "com.hk.web.filter.InAppUrlRedirectFilter.doFilter(InAppUrlRedirectFilter.java:315)"
>   34 = {StackTraceElement@7735}
>   "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)"
>   35 = {StackTraceElement@7736}
>   "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)"
>   36 = {StackTraceElement@7737}
>   "com.hk.web.filter.WebContextFilter.doFilter(WebContextFilter.java:13)"
>   37 = {StackTraceElement@7738}
>   "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)"
>   38 = {StackTraceElement@7739}
>   "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)"
>   39 = {StackTraceElement@7740}
>   "org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)"
>   40 = {StackTraceElement@7741}
>   "org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)"
>   41 = {StackTraceElement@7742}
>   "org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)"
>   42 = {StackTraceElement@7743}
>   "org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)"
>   43 = {StackTraceElement@7744}
>   "org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:387)"
>   44 = {StackTraceElement@7745}
>   "org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)"
>   45 = {StackTraceElement@7746}
>   "org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)"
>   46 = {StackTraceElement@7747}
>   "org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)"
>   47 = {StackTraceElement@7748}
>   "org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)"
>   48 = {StackTraceElement@7749}
>   "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)"
>   49 = {StackTraceElement@7750}
>   "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)"
>   50 = {StackTraceElement@7751}
>   "com.hk.web.filter.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:27)" 
>   51 = {StackTraceElement@7752}
>   "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)"
>   52 = {StackTraceElement@7753}
>   "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)"
>   53 = {StackTraceElement@7754}
>   "org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)"
>   54 = {StackTraceElement@7755}
>   "org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)"
>   55 = {StackTraceElement@7756}
>   "org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)"
>   56 = {StackTraceElement@7757}
>   "org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)"
>   57 = {StackTraceElement@7758}
>   "org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)"
>   58 = {StackTraceElement@7759}
>   "org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)"
>   59 = {StackTraceElement@7760}
>   "org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)"
>   60 = {StackTraceElement@7761}
>   "org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)"
>   61 = {StackTraceElement@7762}
>   "org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)"
>   62 = {StackTraceElement@7763}
>   "org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)"
>   63 = {StackTraceElement@7764}
>   "org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)"
>   64 = {StackTraceElement@7765}
>   "org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)"
>   65 = {StackTraceElement@7766}
>   "org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)"
>   66 = {StackTraceElement@7767}
>   "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)"
>   67 = {StackTraceElement@7768}
>   "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)"
>   68 = {StackTraceElement@7769}
>   "org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)"
>   69 = {StackTraceElement@7770} "java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)"

Answer (score 0):

I do this in the stack trace:

```
com.hk.web.resource.UserResource.loginViaOTP(UserResource.java:365)
```

If you are NOT using Shiro's web filters, then you will need to manage the [Subject creation](https://shiro.apache.org/subject.html#Subject-Subject.Builder) and potentially [thread association](https://shiro.apache.org/subject.html#thread-association) directly.